# 403 Error Virtual Host on sub directory

Tags: apache, apache2, debian, virtualhost, digital-ocean

I am trying to set up Virtual Host on a DigitalOcean Debian droplet. With these settings, the domain goes to the correct place. However, there are broken links in my site and when I try to navigate to `http://ndunn.co.uk/icons`, I get a 403 Error. It seems as though this affects subdirectories, though I cannot be sure. Can anyone help with this?

This is what the contents of `/etc/apache2/sites-available/ndunn.co.uk` looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName ndunn.co.uk
        ServerAlias www.ndunn.co.uk 
        DocumentRoot /var/www/ndunn.co.uk/public_html
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/ndunn.co.uk/public_html>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log 
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: is icons a subdir of /var/www/ndunn.co.uk/public_html?

Comment: @PascalLeMerrer yes `/var/www/ndunn.co.uk/public_html/icons/`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add double quotes on this line:

```
<Directory "/var/www/ndunn.co.uk/public_html">
```

**Update:** the problem could be the location of your config file
From [debian's doc](https://www.debian-administration.org/articles/412):

> Each configuration file in the sites-enabled directory is loaded when the server starts - whilst the files in sites-available are completely ignored.

so you should put your config file in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ndunn.co.uk

Comment: Tried this and restarted Apache - still no luck I'm afraid

Comment: The exact same file already exists in the sites-enabled directory so has already been auto loaded

Comment: Thanks anyway! It's left me completely baffled!